# How to calculate GCP Cloud Run pricing correctly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, price

I am trying to calculate the `GCP Cloud Run` cost if I run the service for a month. In the attached picture, you can see that it did not add the cost for the total number of requests. Cloud Run charges 0.40 USD for one million requests. I think I need to add that cost for the total number of requests on top of the cost it has calculated which is pretty misleading while computing the cost. For example in the UI, we do not have the option to choose the number of requests if we choose `CPU is always allocated`. I know that the warm instances (2 instances) should be running 24/7 for 30 days. So If we calculate 730 hours per month, it would be 1460 hours (5256000 seconds) which means that will incur bills:

`5256000 * 0.00002160 = 113.52596 USD for the CPU cost`. Here 0.00002160 is the price for the vCPU second.

`5256000 * 0.00000240 = 12.61 USD for the memory cost`. Here 0.00000240 is the price for the memory GiB second

So now if we deduct `13402800 - 5256000 = 8146800` we get `8146800 seconds for the CPU` and for the memory we would get `268056000 - 5256000 = 267530400`. So price would come down to this:

```
CPU = 8146800 * 0.00002160 = 175.97
Memory = 267530400 * 0.00000240 = 642.07

Total would be = 175.97 + 642.07 + 113.52 + 12.61 = 944.17 + 4 (1 million request is 0.4 USD = 10 million * 0.4 = 4.00 USD) = 948.17
```

I also tried to calculate this way:

```
CPU cost = 24 * 30 * 0.00002160 * 3600 * 60 = 3359.23

Memory cost = 24 * 30 * 0.00000240 * 3600 * 60 = 373.24 

Total = 3732.47 USD
```

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655523/how-to-estimate-google-cloud-run-costs) answer on StackOverflow but I think it is a wrong calculation.

Can someone break down this cost that matches the output shown by the GCP pricing calculator?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The estimator is quite stupid. After few test, I understood it's configuration.

here some details

- 100 (peak) - 2 (min) = 98 -> number of possible instance up and down. Arbitrary, the calculator say 50% of the time it's UP, 50% of the time is down. Therefore it consider 49 instance up full time in the month, in average.
- In addition of those 49, 2 (the min) are ALWAYS on. therefore, the total number of instance to consider always on in the month in 51.
- 52 * 730 * 3600 -> 134 million .... the number of CPU hour of the calculator.

---

Now, your second way to calculate:

```
CPU cost = 24 * 30 * 0.00002160 * 3600 * 60 = 3359.23
```

Have a close look to the number used:

- 24: number of hour per day
- 30: number of day per month
- 0.0000...: CPU cost
- 3600: number of second per hour
- 60: ???? What's that? the number of instance per months? the number of second per minute? Number of minute per hour? (for the 2 last answer, it's already take into account in the 3600)

---

Final word, when you talk about number, take care of the number. you forgot many 0 and it's difficult to understand your issue.

I don't know if I answered your question. in any case, it's difficult to know exactly the cost of pay as you use product. You can know the max cost, by setting a max instance, and you know you will never go above that threshold, but, if you haven't a clear view on your traffic and the number of request (and you also forgot the egress cost) it's impossible to have a precise estimation.

Comment: Yeah, when I was typing numbers missed some zeros at it seems. Yes, the last 60 was some instance number. I have tried some randomly since I could not figure out the up and down thingy that you have pointed out. Thanks for the breakdown.

Comment: Regarding the egress which I have already estimated. I just wanted to estimate the cost from GCP Cloud Run alone .